# Magento Module Upload Image in Admin

Tags: magento

I'm developing a module with both a frontend and a backend. Until now everything has been ok, but now I want to upload images in the backend. I don't know how to start, and everything I've tried has just given me a headache.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a few days of research, here is an easy to use example of how you can upload files in magento
[How to create an image or video uploader for the Magento Admin Panel](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+to+create+an+image+or+video+uploader+for+the+Magento+Admin+Panel)

Bassically, we need to add the `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` to our form

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    )
);
```

Add a field of type `file` to our fieldset

```
$fieldset->addField('fileinputname', 'file', array(
    'label'     => 'File label',
    'required'  => false,
    'name'      => 'fileinputname',
));
```

And save it in our controller

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileinputname']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['fileinputname']['tmp_name']))) {
  try {
    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));

    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;

    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);

    $data['fileinputname'] = $_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];
  }catch(Exception $e) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong on that one or it doesn't work with 1.4.

Comment: This was tested on 1.9, but you can try with 1.6 that is released as CE.

Answer (score 7):

This needs to go into your module's `etc/system.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <imagesection> <!-- Make up a section key (configuration sidebar) -->
            <!-- ... -->
            <groups>
                <imagegroup> <!-- Make up a group key (the part you can expand/collapse) -->
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <fields>
                        <imagefield> <!-- Make up a field key -->
                            <label>Field Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
                            <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">uploaddir</upload_dir> <!-- would upload into media/uploaddir -->
                            <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">uploaddir</base_url> <!-- same as previous line -->
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </imagefield>
```

Comment: This question is so old, I don't even remember what this code does. I recommend you create a new question.

Comment: you forget coding ? :(

Comment: This actually works perfectly for me on CE 1.7. Uploads the selected image into the specified folder.